# DTS File to disable LCD and use it's GPIO in iMX6ULL

Tags: linux, yocto, device-tree, imx6

I am using the `Toradex` system-on-module colibri `imx6ULL` with a custom board.
I am trying to disable the LCD and use it's GPIOs for my sensors. I have followed the answer in this [link](https://www.toradex.com/community/questions/1788/disable-lcd-for-gpio.html). I got stuck with one of the suggestion in the answer.

> In addition to assigning these pings to an iomuxc pinctrl group, you'll also need to assign the pinctrl group to an enabled node for them to get initialized. You can create a new node specifically for this purpose if you'd like.

1. What does that line mean? Do I need to create a dummy node with `status` property set to `okay`?
2. Can I change of the name appearing in /dev/ for uart port?
3. How can I enable `JTAG` in my custom board?

My device tree source file is below:

```
/dts-v1/;

#include "imx6ull-colibri-nonwifi.dtsi"
#include "imx6ull-colibri-eval-v3.dtsi"

/ {
    model = "Toradex Colibri iMX6ULL 256MB on Colibri Evaluation Board V3";
    compatible = "toradex,colibri_imx6ull-eval", "fsl,imx6ull";

    &uart1 {
        status = "okay";
    };

    &uart2 {
        status = "okay";
    };

    &uart3 {
        status = "okay";
    };

    &uart4 {
        status = "disabled";
    };

    &uart5 {
        status = "disabled";
    };


    &ecspi1 {
        status = "okay";
    };

    &i2c1 {
        status = "okay";

        /* M41T0M6 real time clock on carrier board */
        rtc: m41t0m6@68 {
            status = "disabled";
        };
    };



    &pwm1 {
        status = "okay";
    };

    &pwm2 {
        status = "okay";
    };



    &lcdif {
        status = "disabled";
    };

    &iomux {
        imx6ull-colibri {
            pinctrl_additionalgpio: additionalgpios {
                fsl,pins = <
                    MX6UL_PAD_UART2_RTS_B__GPIO1_IO23 0x14      // Pin 34 => GPS SafeBoot
                    MX6UL_PAD_CSI_DATA00__GPIO4_IO21  0x14      // Pin 101 => 1V8 Power Supply Enable
                    MX6UL_PAD_LCD_ENABLE__GPIO3_IO01  0x14      // Pin 44 => GPS EXINT
                    MX6UL_PAD_LCD_DATA07__GPIO3_IO12  0x14      // Pin 46 => GPS RST
                    MX6UL_PAD_LCD_DATA09__GPIO3_IO14  0x14      // Pin 48 => UNUSED
                    MX6UL_PAD_LCD_DATA06__GPIO3_IO11  0x14      // Pin 80 => SX1301 RST
                >;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

The device tree `imx6ull-colibri-nonwifi.dtsi` can be found over [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ull-colibri-nonwifi.dtsi).

The device tree `imx6ull-colibri-eval-v3.dtsi` can be found over [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6ull-colibri-eval-v3.dtsi).

**EDIT:**

I have tried few times on my own after reading some documents online on `dts`. Find the latest version of my dts below. I have also found out `SPI` is not working in my board so that I have edited my dts to include spi.

I have added a dummy node to enable gpio.

```
/dts-v1/;

#include "imx6ull-colibri-nonwifi.dtsi"
#include "imx6ull-colibri-eval-v3.dtsi"

/ {
    model = "Toradex Colibri iMX6ULL 256MB on Colibri Evaluation Board V3";
    compatible = "toradex,colibri_imx6ull-eval", "fsl,imx6ull";

    &uart1 {
        status = "okay";
    };

    &uart2 {
        status = "okay";
    };

    &uart3 {
        status = "okay";
    };

    &uart4 {
        status = "disabled";
    };

    &uart5 {
        status = "disabled";
    };


    &ecspi1 {
        status = "okay";
    };

    &i2c1 {
        status = "okay";

        /* M41T0M6 real time clock on carrier board */
        rtc: m41t0m6@68 {
            status = "disabled";
        };
    };



    &pwm1 {
        status = "okay";
    };

    &pwm2 {
        status = "okay";
    };



    &lcdif {
        status = "disabled";
    };

    gpio_additional {
        pinctrl-name = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_additionalgpio>;
        status = "okay";
    };

    &ecspi1 {
        status = "okay";

    };

    &iomux {
        imx6ull-colibri {
            pinctrl_additionalgpio: additionalgpios {
                fsl,pins = <
                    MX6UL_PAD_UART2_RTS_B__GPIO1_IO23 0x14      // Pin 34 => GPS SafeBoot
                    MX6UL_PAD_CSI_DATA00__GPIO4_IO21  0x14      // Pin 101 => 1V8 Power Supply Enable
                    MX6UL_PAD_LCD_ENABLE__GPIO3_IO01  0x14      // Pin 44 => GPS EXINT
                    MX6UL_PAD_LCD_DATA07__GPIO3_IO12  0x14      // Pin 46 => GPS RST
                    MX6UL_PAD_LCD_DATA09__GPIO3_IO14  0x14      // Pin 48 => UNUSED
                    MX6UL_PAD_LCD_DATA06__GPIO3_IO11  0x14      // Pin 80 => SX1301 RST
                >;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) It means you need to add the pinctrl-group e.g. the one you have created `pinctrl_additionalgpio` to a node.

I'll take for instance the lcdif node you have disabled in you device-tree to illustrate a pinctrl-group added to a node. In this example, `pinctrl_lcdif_dat` and `pinctrl_lcdif_ctrl` are added to the `lcdif` node:

```
&lcdif {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_lcdif_dat
             &pinctrl_lcdif_ctrl>;
};
```

You have to either create a node of your own and add the pinctrl-group or find a suitable node, e.g.:

```
myadditionalgpio {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_additionalgpio>;
};
```

2) I have not ever got as far as changing the name of the device. If all you need is to have an alternative name, you can use a udev rule to create a symlink:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/rename-uart.rules
KERNEL=="ttymxc0", SYMLINK+="test_serial"
```

Then you will have a `/dev/test_serial` device that points to `/dev/ttymxc0`.

3) You can have a look at the generic JTAG Toradex documentation https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/jtag.

Comment: Notice that in your device tree posted in the question above, you refer to `&iomux` which does not exist. You may fix that by replacing it to `&iomuxc`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Please check my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51884314/device-tree-for-changing-uart-mode-and-enabling-gpios-for-imx6ull-system-on-modu

Comment: Hi @abhiarora, even though I'm OK with answering here, would you mind posting in the Toradex community? https://www.toradex.com/community
There you will have a team of Toradex people looking at your question and a faster answer.

Comment: I have posted over there as well. Here is the link: https://www.toradex.com/community/questions/27640/device-tree-for-uart-in-dce-mode-for-imx6ull-modul.html