# Device Tree for changing UART Mode and enabling GPIOs for iMX6ULL System-on-module

Tags: linux, uart, gpio, device-tree, imx6

I am using `iMX6ULL` system-on-module on my custom board.

I am struggling with UART, GPIOs of my custom board. I have solved the SPI issue on my board but later I got to know about another issue with my board and that's why I thought to ask a new question.

I am able to activate desired UART port and SPI port for my board. But I got to know that my peripheral sensors which are soldered on my custom board have TX and RX lines swapped. I was trying to swap tx rx pins of `UART5` of the imx6ull soc with `device tree` modification. For that, I am trying to enable `DCE Mode` for uart5 (By Default, colibri module has `DTE` mode activated). However, when i define (redefine) `pinctrl-0` and `pinctrl-name` properties in my upper `dts` file, then uart tty port under `/dev/` directory disappears. I have tried to point `pinctrl-0` to `pinctrl_uart5_their` and `pinctrl_uart5_own`. The `pinctrl_uart5_their` is copy of `pinctrl_uart5` defined in `imx6ull-colibri.dtsi` file. But the uart port under `/dev/` directory disappears. If I comment out `pinctrl` properties (it means the properties are taken from include files), then uart port appears.

`GPIOs` are also not working properly. I tried to test them by exporting them by following a [guide](https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/gpio-(linux)) on toradex developer site and writing 1 and 0 after changing the direction using appropriate commands but it doesn't work for me as output is not reflected on the pins.

Please help me by verifying my device tree and suggesting me the right way to do it.

The device tree is over here:

```
/dts-v1/;
#include "imx6ull-colibri-nonwifi.dtsi"
#include "imx6ull-colibri-eval-v3.dtsi"

/ {
    model = "Toradex Colibri iMX6ULL 256MB on Colibri Evaluation Board V3";
    compatible = "toradex,colibri_imx6ull-eval", "fsl,imx6ull";


    gpio_additional {
        pinctrl-name = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_additionalgpio>;
        status = "okay";
    };
};


&iomuxc {
    imx6ull-colibri {
        pinctrl_additionalgpio: additionalgpios {
            fsl,pins = <
                MX6UL_PAD_UART2_RTS_B__GPIO1_IO23 0x14      // Pin 34 => GPS SafeBoot
                MX6UL_PAD_CSI_DATA00__GPIO4_IO21  0x14      // Pin 101 => 1V8 Power Supply Enable
                MX6UL_PAD_LCD_ENABLE__GPIO3_IO01  0x14      // Pin 44 => GPS EXINT
                MX6UL_PAD_LCD_DATA07__GPIO3_IO12  0x14      // Pin 46 => GPS RST
                MX6UL_PAD_LCD_DATA09__GPIO3_IO14  0x14      // Pin 48 => UNUSED
                MX6UL_PAD_LCD_DATA06__GPIO3_IO11  0x14      // Pin 80 => SX1301 RST
            >;
        };
    };

    pinctrl_uart5_their: uart5grp_their {
        fsl,pins = <
            MX6UL_PAD_GPIO1_IO04__UART5_DTE_RX  0x1b0b1
            MX6UL_PAD_GPIO1_IO05__UART5_DTE_TX  0x1b0b1
        >;
    };

    pinctrl_uart5_own: uart5grp_own {
        fsl,pins = <
            MX6UL_PAD_GPIO1_IO05__UART5_DCE_RX  0x1b0b1
            MX6UL_PAD_GPIO1_IO04__UART5_DCE_TX  0x1b0b1
        >;
    };
};


&uart1 {
    status = "okay";
};

&uart2 {
    status = "okay";
    /delete-property/fsl,dte-mode;
    fsl,dce-mode;
};

&uart3 {
    status = "disabled";
};

&uart4 {
    status = "disabled";
};

&uart5 {
    status = "okay";

    pinctrl-name = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_uart5_own>;

    /delete-property/fsl,dte-mode;
    fsl,dce-mode;
};


&ecspi1 {
    status = "okay";
};

&i2c1 {
    status = "okay";

    /* M41T0M6 real time clock on carrier board */
    rtc: m41t0m6@68 {
        status = "disabled";
    };
};


&pwm1 {
    status = "okay";
};

&pwm2 {
    status = "okay";
};


&lcdif {
    status = "disabled";
};

&ecspi1 {
    status = "okay";
};

&mcp258x0 {
    status = "disabled";
};

&spidev0 {
    status = "okay";
};
```

**EDIT:**

I have resolved the issue of UART port being disappeared. The issue was with my device tree as my `pinctrl_uart5_their` nodes weren't under `imx6ull-colibri` node (see `iomuxc` in device tree above).

But I am not able to swap the TX RX Pins of UART5 with DTB. I have found few posts which says it is possible. Also, GPIOs are not working even after following this [guide](https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/gpio-(linux)). Find the snapshot of my terminal below:

```
root@colibri-imx6ull:~# echo 75 > /sys/class/gpio/export                        
root@colibri-imx6ull:~# echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio75/direction           
root@colibri-imx6ull:~# echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio75/value                   
root@colibri-imx6ull:~# echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio75/value                   
root@colibri-imx6ull:~# echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio75/value                   
root@colibri-imx6ull:~# echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio75/value                   
root@colibri-imx6ull:~# cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio                              
gpiochip0: GPIOs 0-31, parent: platform/209c000.gpio, 209c000.gpio:             
 gpio-2   (                    |VCC_USB[1-4]        ) out lo                    
 gpio-11  (                    |enable              ) out hi                    

gpiochip1: GPIOs 32-63, parent: platform/20a0000.gpio, 20a0000.gpio:            

gpiochip2: GPIOs 64-95, parent: platform/20a4000.gpio, 20a4000.gpio:            
 gpio-75  (                    |sysfs               ) out hi                    
 gpio-90  (                    |spi_imx             ) out hi                    

gpiochip3: GPIOs 96-127, parent: platform/20a8000.gpio, 20a8000.gpio:           

gpiochip4: GPIOs 128-159, parent: platform/20ac000.gpio, 20ac000.gpio:          
 gpio-128 (                    |cd                  ) in  lo                    
 gpio-129 (                    |Wake-Up             ) in  lo                    
 gpio-130 (                    |id                  ) in  lo
```

**Pin 80 in SODIMM pin corresponds to Kernel number `75`.**

The latest device is below:

/dts-v1/;

```
#include "imx6ull-colibri-nonwifi.dtsi"
#include "imx6ull-colibri-eval-v3.dtsi"

/ {
    model = "Toradex Colibri iMX6ULL 256MB on Colibri Evaluation Board V3";
    compatible = "toradex,colibri_imx6ull-eval", "fsl,imx6ull";


    gpio_additional {
        pinctrl-name = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_additionalgpio>;
        status = "okay";
    };
};


&iomuxc {
    imx6ull-colibri {
        pinctrl_additionalgpio: additionalgpios {
            fsl,pins = <
                MX6UL_PAD_UART2_RTS_B__GPIO1_IO23 0x14          // Pin 34 => GPS SafeBoot
                MX6UL_PAD_CSI_DATA00__GPIO4_IO21  0x14          // Pin 101 => 1V8 Power Supply Enable
                MX6UL_PAD_LCD_ENABLE__GPIO3_IO01  0x14          // Pin 44 => GPS EXINT
                MX6UL_PAD_LCD_DATA07__GPIO3_IO12  0x14          // Pin 46 => GPS RST
                MX6UL_PAD_LCD_DATA09__GPIO3_IO14  0x14          // Pin 48 => UNUSED
                MX6UL_PAD_LCD_DATA06__GPIO3_IO11  0x14          // Pin 80 => SX1301 RST
            >;
        };


        pinctrl_uart5_their: uart5grp_their {
            fsl,pins = <
                MX6UL_PAD_GPIO1_IO04__UART5_DTE_RX  0x1b0b1
                MX6UL_PAD_GPIO1_IO05__UART5_DTE_TX  0x1b0b1
            >;
        };

        pinctrl_uart5_own: uart5grp_own {
            fsl,pins = <
                MX6UL_PAD_GPIO1_IO04__UART5_DCE_TX  0x1b0b1
                MX6UL_PAD_GPIO1_IO05__UART5_DCE_RX  0x1b0b1
            >;
        };

    };
};


&uart1 {
    status = "okay";
};

&uart2 {
    status = "okay";
    /delete-property/fsl,dte-mode;
    fsl,dce-mode;
};

&uart3 {
    status = "disabled";
};

&uart4 {
    status = "disabled";
};

&uart5 {
    status = "okay";

    pinctrl-name = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_uart5_own>;

    // /delete-property/fsl,dte-mode;
    // fsl,dce-mode;
};


&ecspi1 {
    status = "okay";
};

&i2c1 {
    status = "okay";

    /* M41T0M6 real time clock on carrier board */
    rtc: m41t0m6@68 {
        status = "disabled";
    };
};


&pwm1 {
    status = "okay";
};

&pwm2 {
    status = "okay";
};


&lcdif {
    status = "disabled";
};

&ecspi1 {
    status = "okay";
};

&mcp258x0 {
    status = "disabled";
};

&spidev0 {
    status = "okay";
};
```